# How can I allow ssh host keys to be added again?

Tags: networking, ssh

A couple years ago for a project I was doing at work, I disabled ssh host key checking (we made a buinch of different machines with the same static IP address). I can't remember what I did to disable it. Every time I try to connect to a host I get:

```
The authenticity of host 'XXXXXXX (XXX.XXX.X.X)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX.
```

And I have to verify it each time. Unfortunately now I'm using an application that requires the host to be saved otherwise it won't connect.

I can't remember what I did to disable it.

How is what I did normally done and how do I reverse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you have a `~/.ssh/` directory and a `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file in it. Maybe you replaced the file with a symlink to `/dev/null`?

Also check if your `~/.ssh/config` (or the global `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) is configured to use a different location for the `UserKnownHostsFile`.

Comment: I deleted my known hosts file, it wasn't symlinked to anything but there was something about it that was off apparently.